# How to keep MacBook awake with lid closed + extended display?

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

Specs:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.1
- MacBook Pro 15-inch, early 2011

Basically, when I connect my projector and extend the display, after closing the lid, MacBook "extended display" option cancels out and I can see the full display (not just the extended bit). I understand this phenomenon happens because of the "closed-clamshell" mode, however what I want to achieve is to be able to close my MacBook Pro's lid and see the extended display on the wall - when I open the lid, I should be able to see the usual display on my laptop and still the extended one on the wall.

Used the latest versions of both NoSleep & Caffeine (also tried InsomniaX), but no luck.

Comment: So you want your laptop to stay the main screen, even though it's closed and you won't be able to see it?

Answer (score 1):

Requirements for closed-display mode from, [Use your Mac notebook computer in closed-display mode with an external display](https://support.apple.com/HT201834):

> To use closed-display mode with your Mac notebook, you need:
>
> - An AC power adapter
> - An external keyboard and mouse or trackpad, either USB or wireless
> - A USB-C to USB adapter if you're using a USB mouse or keyboard with MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015) and later or MacBook Pro models introduced in late 2016
> - An external display or projector
>
> If you're using a USB keyboard and mouse
>
> 1. Make sure that your Mac notebook is plugged in to an outlet using the AC power adapter.
> 2. Connect a USB keyboard and mouse to your Mac.
> 3. With your Mac turned on and the display open, connect the Mac to the appropriate port on the external display or projector and turn the display or projector on.
> 4. Use an appropriate Apple video adapter if necessary.
> 5. After your Mac notebook's Desktop appears on the external display, close the computer's lid.
>      When you close the lid: 
>      In OS X Lion v10.7 and later, the external display changes to a blue screen, then shows your Desktop.
>      In OS X v10.6.8 and earlier, you can wake your Mac by clicking the mouse button or pressing a key on the external keyboard.

You can now use your Mac notebook as you normally would with a USB keyboard and mouse.